# UITableViewCell rotate lags/hangs if I set UIImage as background view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I am setting a UIImage, via a UIImageView as my background view of a subclassed UITableViewCell like so:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {

UIImage *backImg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"CellBackground"]  
                    resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(16, 132, 16, 16)];
UIImageView *imv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backImg];
self.backgroundView = imv;

}
```

This works excellently, each cell is different in height (exposed via heightForRowAtIndexPath which calculates the height of a UILabel with text in it), and the background image resizes as I want the cell to.

However, when I rotate the device, the view hangs mid rotate, and takes 5-10 seconds to redraw in landscape, or crashes with no error. If I remove this imageview from the backgroundView, the rotate works excellently. Both simulator and device.

[Edit] Alternatively, I added the imageview as a subview of the cell.contentView - performance was better, but still laggy.

```
UIImage *backImg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"CellBackground"]  
                    resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(16, 132, 16, 16)];
UIImageView *imv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
imv.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
imv.image = backImg;

[self.contentView addSubview:imv];
```

Additionally, as mentioned above, my UITableViewCell is a subclass. The above code is in awakeFromNib, and I'm loading in my UITableViewCell like so:

```
// within initWithNibName: of UIViewcontroller:

cellLoader = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MasterTableViewCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

// and UITableView method:

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    MasterTableViewCell *cell = (MasterTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MasterTableViewCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelItems = [cellLoader instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelItems objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling this every time you draw a cell? This can really hurt your performance. I would suggest only doing this when drawing a new cell. So it would look like

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(cell == nil) 
{
    UIImage *backImg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"CellBackground"]  
                resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(16, 132, 16, 16)];
    UIImageView *imv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    imv.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    imv.image = backImg;

    [self.contentView addSubview:imv];
}
```

Comment: You're leaking, autorelease the imv.

Comment: Yeah sorry. Did a quick copy paste

Comment: Thanks Jay - This code is placed in my awakefromnib method. I've updated my post above to explain in more detail. However even using your suggestion I get the same performance lag...

Comment: Because you have an autoresizing mask when you rotate the device it is resizing each cell and each cells image. Have you tried removing the autoresizing code and rotating it? This could let you know if the problem is with resizing the images. Also How large is the image?